# Does Gameranger on Linux work for any multiplayer game?

Tags: linux, gameranger, battle-for-middle-earth

I tried playing Battle for Middle Earth online with Gameranger through Wine, and when I host or join a game BFME will start up, but when I go to the Network lobby my game just freezes. I'm trying to figure out if Gameranger works for any Linux game, or if this is just one game in particular that has this problem.

---

Author technical edit (1 year later) - This particular issue might root in how the engine for BFME and C&C only look for LAN in the first network device you have. Network device order is handled quite a bit differently between Windows and Linux, which could explain why this is tricky. [Source](https://github.com/Linux-BFME/Installers/blob/master/FAQ.md#in-network-lobby-i-dont-see-other-people-on-my-lan)

---

Update: I've since tried this with

<strike>`wine-5.4`</strike>

<strike>`wine-5.18 (Staging)`</strike>

`wine 6.9`

No luck. Maybe in the future?

Comment: Same happens for me in c&c zero hour. Have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: I'm also seeing this in BFME2